# Is this a proper use of a semicolon?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

Is this a correctly formed sentence? In formal writing does the sentence need to be broken into two sentences?

> As an example consider Myc; when overexpressed it can be a powerful promoter of uncontrolled cell division, yet without accompanying anti-apoptotic mutations, induces cell death.

Comment: No, that should be a colon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this actually requires a colon and some other punctuation. I see that overexpressed has a lot of precedence in the field.

> As an example consider Myc: when overexpressed, it can be a powerful promoter of uncontrolled cell division, yet without accompanying anti-apoptotic mutations, induces cell death.

As far as your question about breaking it into two sentences, I'd say no (you could of course). Technical writing, if it's clear, can benefit a ([*SME*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject-matter_expert)) reader for it to be doled out in larger, but still manageable chunks of information, *particularly* when the parts interrelate so closely as they do here.

And I don't know what it is, but I do like saying "anti-[apoptotic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apoptosis) mutations".

Answer (score 5):

I would use a full colon there because the second part is an elaboration of the first statement.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, you're using an appositive, albeit a long one, and those are properly set off with colons.

> Some sports are played on a field; chief among them is the US's national **pastime**: **baseball**.

In your example, *Myc* functions like *pastime* and the rest functions like *baseball*.

And although it's not what you asked about, I'd personally drop the "As an example," and start with

> Consider Myc: when overexpressed, it can be a powerful promoter...

I would also consider dropping the passive voice: ("promotes" rather than "is a promoter"), which would also create symmetry with "induces."

For less formal writing, I might be tempted to use a dash in place of the colon.

- http://englishplus.com/grammar/00000100.htm
- http://www.grammar-quizzes.com/punc-examples.html

Answer (score -1):

A semicolon is a blur between a comma and a period (full-stop). It is required when joining two independent clauses that are related but cannot be joined with a conjunction. Something that would require lesser pause in reading than a period, but more than that of a comma. You can find more information about it [here](http://theoatmeal.com/comics/semicolon)

> [C1] As an example consider Myc; [C2] when overexpressed it can be a powerful promoter of uncontrolled cell division, yet without accompanying anti-apoptotic mutations, induces cell death.

The use of the semicolon is justified in your context. C1 and C2 are independent clauses that would be grammatically fine with a period separating them, but when speaking, it would sound better when the pause is less, hence a semicolon is used to connect them.

There are cases where the use of a colon and semicolon are both applicable. This is just one of them. Note that under the use of a colon, it is not always necessary that the clauses are to be independent as it is required for a semicolon.

Comment: The second clause actually *elaborates on* consideration of Myc. A colon might be more appropriate. Also, while it's outside the scope of the question, the last part of the sentence "yet without accompanying anti-apoptotic mutations [...]" is not correct. Instead, the preceding comma should be removed and the word "yet" replaced with "but".

Comment: @RMac Actually, there ought to be a comma between *overexpressed*  and *it*. Read it again, you will find that it makes perfect sense in continuation of the previous clause taken as a sentence. To make it clearer, you can state it as *"it can be a powerful promoter of uncontrolled cell division when overexpressed, yet..."* Is there anything else?

Comment: Also, as you point out, there are missing commas. I also have changed my mind in retrospect about the use of "but" and think "or" with the comma fits better. See: "[C1] As an **example, consider Myc:** [C2] when **overexpressed,** it can be a powerful promoter of uncontrolled cell division, **or,** without accompanying anti-apoptotic mutations, **can induce** death."

Comment: Although your use of the colon *is* applicable, the use of a semicolon is more apt. Usually, when using a colon, the clauses mostly won't be independent, but it is always the case in semicolon. Refer [this](http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/colons.asp).

Comment: See rule #4 on the link you posted. "A colon instead of a semicolon may be used between independent clauses when the second sentence explains, illustrates, paraphrases, or expands on the first sentence."

Comment: @RMac Again, clause independence is only a subset of the colon's variants; it is a necessity for the semicolon. Besides, I never stated your use of the colon is wrong: it's also applicable.

Answer (score -1):

Going through this will help you master the use of a semicolon! Let's get it started! 
**Usages**:-
1. **To add two closely related independent clauses**.
• *You do not look fine; you should go back home and take some rest*.

> **Explanation**: the reason we have used a semicolon here is because both the sentences are focusing on one thing: your health. Since they are closely related to each other, we we have used a semicolon.
>   *• I went to a party last night; it was the best one I have been a part of.*
>   **Explanation: **Both these sentences are talking about the same thing: the party. Since one's meaning is related to another, we have used asemicolon and shown a relation.
>
> **2.  Use a semicolon before conjunctive adverbs to add two independent clauses**.
>   **Conjunctive adverbs**: however, still, nonetheless, nevertheless, likewise, moreover, subsequently, consequently, then, for example etc.,
>   ***Examples***:-
>   • *Johnny does a lot of stupid things; however, he is my best friend.*
>   *• Our team has been playing flawlessly; therefore, all the players are confident to win the final.*

**3. Use semicolons to separate a list of items that have further information about them separated by commas.**

• Meet my best friends: Archit, Monu, and Nona.
Let's have more information about these items in the list and separate them using comma and see how the sentence looks!

> • **Meet my best friends: Archit, my childhood buddy, Monu, the one I love the most, and Nona, my beautiful girlfriend.**
>   Doesn't it look confusing? Yes, it does. So, that's why we need semicolons to separate the items in the list.
>   • **Meet my best friends: Archit, my childhood buddy; Monu, the one I love the most; and Nona, my beautiful girlfriend.**
>
> ---
>
> *• We are going to visit a couple of places next month: Goa, my favourite place; the Taj Mahal, one of the seven wonders of the world; and vellingiri hills, in Bengaluru*.
>   • *He has taken a couple of people in his team: Rahul, responsible for the tech support; Jack, the voice support; and me, as the head of the team.*
>   **
>   4. To wink. 
>   ;)

***Important points:-***

**1. The first letter of the word coming after the semicolon should not be capitalised.**
• It is not safe outside; keep everyone inside.
***Exceptions***:-
***A) ******When the word coming after is a proper noun******.***
Ex - let's have dinner at my place; Riya, my sister, cooks amazing food.
***B) When the first word is I.***
Ex - Let's have dinner at my place; I cook amazing food.

**2. Do not use a semicolon to join two sentences that are not related to each other!**
 • She lives in England; my father is a doctor.** ❌**

**3. Do not use a semicolon if any of the two clauses are not independent - sentence.**
• I hate him; though he is my friend. ❌
• I hate him though he is my friend.  ✔

> **Note**: Please do not overuse a semicolon! It has a special usage, so use it at the right time.

Watch this lesson to master it completely and take your writing to a different level: Writing master series #2 -   All usages of a SEMICOLON and a COLON in English || Expert writing ✍ (https://youtu.be/-DRB5kiKkgI)